# Not able to click a button using Selenium and Java. It has "style=display: none" in html which is causing issue

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have tried with different xpaths etc but not able to click a 'Continue' button in my application. Following is one of the attempt to handle the same:-

```
WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    WebElement continueBtn = wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@type = 'submit' and @class = 'btn btn--primary']")));
```

When I inspect element I find follwing details in it: -

```
 <button class="btn btn--primary" type="submit" data-bind="enable: !processing() &amp;&amp; !$root.accountLocked()">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon shape--loader" style="display: none;" viewBox="0 0 16 16" focusable="false" data-bind="visible: processing()">
                <title>Processing</title>
                <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#shape--loader" />
            </svg> 
            Continue
        </button>
```

The error thrown is as follow:-
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //*[@type = 'submit' and @class = 'btn btn--primary']

However the object/element was already loaded so not sure why it couldn't click the element.

I also tried JavaScript executor but to no avail.

Please help me resolve it. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Add the stack trace of the exception? why u need to click display none element? are u testing or scrapping? How u click them manually? is it getting enabled after processing something?

Comment: Manually it is clickable during manual testing. While automating it is not getting clicked even tried with different xpaths, css selector etc.This is actually a button with name 'Continue' and it has to be clicked after user enters answer of an MFA question. The server didn't provide stack trace.

Comment: You mean wait until clickable is working and after that click code ran without error. But the click action is not simulated in application . right?

Comment: Navarasu, after running the code it is throwing exception and not clicking the element I want my script to hit, so this is error for me.

Comment: What is the exception ur getting? Please add the stacktrace of the exception message ur getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. Before reaching solution I tried explicit wait, code of which I had pasted in question itself and then tried with JavaScript executor but it also didn't work. Following is the solution:-

```
    Actions action = new Actions(driver); 
    action.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

It worked perfactly fine. Thank you guys who all contributed their time and efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clear the air, is the XPath given above is unique? 
If yes did you give it a try with JSExecutor?

Try with below code:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@type = 'submit' and @class = 'btn btn--primary']")));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. Xpath written in question part is not unique. With same xpath there is one more element. So how to handle that. What you suggest?

Comment: add '[1]' next to your xpath to make it unique as below. `//*[@type = 'submit' and @class = 'btn btn--primary'][1]`

Comment: Mark the answer as helpful to close the thread if your issue is resolved.

Comment: Bradz, I tried your suggestion twice but it didn't work.Thanks for your time and efforts. Please see if you have any other suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If it is difficult to findelement with attributes, then find it based on button name. If there is only one Continue button in the page like.

```
WebElement continueBtn = wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Continue')]")));
```

Comment: Thanks navarasu, for your time & efforts. But this didn't work.

Comment: In dev console, if you serach with above xpath. are your getting single locator? if it is one, what is the error ur getting while clicking? if you are not getting error, is it enabled while clicking, coz, i see it is enabled based on some condition?

Comment: Navarasu, I was digging html and realised that “style=display: none” , so selenium is not able to find the hidden element. I tried with CSS selector and xpath as well. I tried with JS executor but still not able to find the element. Great Thanks for your help and efforts.